# Need help figuring out how to parse and extract port-mode a file?

Tags: python, juniper, junos-automation, ciscoconfparse

I have a text file that contains the following information:

```
interfaces {
ge-2/0/0 {
    description "site1;;hostname1;ge-16/0/9;;;TRUST;";
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            port-mode trunk;
        }
    }
}
ge-2/0/2 {
    description "site2;;hostname2;ge-16/0/8;;;TRUST;";
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            port-mode trunk;
        }
    }
}
```

With the help of others I've been able to extract the interface id (ge-2/0/0) as well as the description.

The code for that is as follows:

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
parse = CiscoConfParse("testconfig.txt", syntax="junos")

intfs = parse.find_objects_w_parents(r'^interfaces', r'^\s+ge-')
for intfobj in intfs:
    intf_name = intfobj.text.strip()
    descr = intfobj.re_match_iter_typed(r'description\s+"(\S.+?)"$', group=1)
    print ('Intf: {0}, {1}'.format(intf_name, descr))
```

This gives me a result of:

```
Intf: ge-2/0/0, site1;;hostname1;ge-16/0/9;;;TRUST;
Intf: ge-2/0/2, site2;;hostname2;ge-16/0/8;;;TRUST;
```

So far that's been huge for me, and I really thought I was going to be able to figure out how to dig deeper into the interface to extract the "port-mode".

My attempts so far are failing me.

This is the general train of thought I had in trying to dig that info out but to no avail:

```
ltype = parse.find_objects_w_parents(r'^interfaces', r'^\s+ge-', r'^unit\s0', r'^family\sethernet-switching')
for ltypeobj in ltype:
    pmode = intfobj.re_match_iter_typed(r'port-mode\s+"(\S.+?)"$', group=1)
    print ('Port Mode: {0}'.format(pmode))
```

I get the following and I'm just not able to figure it out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 11, in <module>
    ltype = parse.find_objects_w_parents(r'^interfaces', r'^\s+ge-', r'^unit\s0', r'^family\sethernet-switching')
TypeError: find_objects_w_parents() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Any advice on accomplishing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check if this example works for you

```
import re
for i in re.findall('(ge-\d/\d/\d).*\n\s+description\s+(.*)(\n\s+.*){2}\n\s+port-mode\s(.*);', x):
    print 'interface: ', i[0]
    print 'description: ', i[1]
    print 'port mode: ', i[-1]
```

output:

```
interface:  ge-2/0/0
description:  "site1;;hostname1;ge-16/0/9;;;TRUST;";
port mode:  trunk
interface:  ge-2/0/2
description:  "site2;;hostname2;ge-16/0/8;;;TRUST;";
port mode:  trunk
```

Comment: How in the world did you accomplish all of that with that one line. I just don't even understand.